# R corrplot Package Won't Load in Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi, r-corrplot

I tried to use R's corrplot package in power BI but when I ran the script library(corrplot) and got an error stating there's no package called corrplot but it works in R studio. In the Microsoft page it says this packages is supported. Does anybody know why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have much experience with R.

Just use some R code in Power BI. If you have the following error message from Power BI, you should install the corrplot package in R script editor in Power BI.

Running the below would solve the issue. After installing the package and R-plot is executed properly, you can remove the install.packages line.

```
install.packages("corrplot", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
require("corrplot")
library(corrplot)
```

[R_corrplot_errorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaUco.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate how this answers the original question? Based on the question, the asker had 'corrplot' installed, but it was not being recognized by Power BI.  Your response just looks like a re-installation. So it's unclear whether it will resolve the asker's situation.

Comment: I just modified my answer to make it clearer. I am not acquainted with R, but have to use R in Power BI and could not run corrplot in Power BI and got the similar error message as Alexander got. The issue was not having corrplot package in Power BI, thus running the install.packages resolve that issue in my case.